# no puedo ver las imagenes que suben los clientes a mi formulario

Tags: html, css, reactjs, formularios, input-file

tengo un problema y es que hice un formulario donde el cliente puede subir imágenes o archivos(lo hice con un input file) pero cuando me llega la información del usuario no puedo abrir el archivo (la información me llega gracias a una api se llama form-submit) a continuación les dejo el código hecho con react.js

```
 <div className="buttons"> 
    <div className='file-select' id='src-file1'>
      <input className="file" type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    </div>
```

al input file luego lo edite con css para que quede mas estetico.

Comment: Pero qué no puedes verlo por qué? Osea, que error tienes o sale en el código?

Comment: en el código no me sale ningún error, cuando me llega la información que el usuario puso en el formulario(me llega al Gmail) simplemente no puedo abrir el archivo, si puedo ver que tipo de formato es (png, pdf, etc...) y el nombre del archivo pero no puedo abrirlo

Comment: ya encontré el error en la linea del form me faltaba el enctype="multipart/form-data"